# Can I note unofficial classes I plan to take on my CV for graduate admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, application-cover-letter

I'm writing CV for a grad school; Fall semester in 2017. 
I will work as TA and take several fundamental courses from unofficial school which are related to the areas that I will study in the grad school. This event will begin in Jan. for three months.

And I'm wondering that where I could note this upcoming event.

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: What is an "unofficial school" in this context?

Comment: it is like a boot camp(academy) for learning advanced skills

Comment: I don't know what a boot camp for learning advanced skills is, exactly, but maybe it's more relevant in your field/location than mine.  Couldn't you just list it on your CV under education?

Answer (score 2):

**In general, I'd warn against listing things you plan to do (but have not done) on your curriculum vitæ**.

**Should you list courses you've taken completed outside of formal educational environments (e.g. in MOOCs like Coursera, etc)? Sure!** Especially if you think it helps address other shortcomings or holes on your application.

Just make sure that these these courses (as well as everything else) is listed in a way that is makes it accurately conveys the nature of the achievement. For example, if you completed a course on edX, list the course, list the fact that it was on edX, indicate whether you completed it, and consider providing any scores on final exams if applicable, etc.